# How to communicate between UserControl in MVVM - WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I want to create an application with a menu on the left that will change the content on the right.
For that, I Have a MainWindow with two ContentControl (One that will Content a UserControl 'Menu' and the other one that will Content the selected UserControl 'Red' or 'Green'.

The problem is that the Content on the right does not Change...

I have made some research and saw concepts like Dependency Injection, Delegate, Event, Message Bus, ViewModelLocator...
but I don't know which one would be the most suitable in this case and how to implement it. (I don't want to use MVVMLight or any PlugIn like that)

Thx in advance for your interest.

For that I use the MVVM pattern and DataTemplate Binding:

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:MainViewModel}">
        <view:MainWindow />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModelMenu:LeftViewModel}">
        <viewMenu:Left />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModelContent:RedViewModel}">
        <viewContent:Red />
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

ViewModel.cs

```
public abstract class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Properties

    private ViewModel _mainContent;

    public ViewModel MainContent
    {
        get => _mainContent;
        set
        {
            _mainContent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            MessageBox.Show(nameof(MainContent));
        }
    }

    #endregion Properties

    public ViewModel()
    {
        InitCommands();
    }

    protected abstract void InitCommands();

    #region Factory Method - CreateCommand

    protected ICommand CreateCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        return new RelayCommand(
            execute: execute,
            canExecute: canExecute
            );
    }

    protected ICommand CreateCommand<T>(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
    {
        return new RelayCommand<T>(
            execute: execute,
            canExecute: canExecute
            );
    }

    #endregion Factory Method - CreateCommand

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
internal class MainViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private ViewModel _leftMenu;
    public ViewModel LeftMenu
    {
        get => _leftMenu;
        set
        {
            _leftMenu = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        LeftMenu = new LeftViewModel();
    }

    protected override void InitCommands()
    {
    }
```

LeftViewModel.cs

```
internal class LeftViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public ICommand ChangeContentToRed { get; set; }
    public ICommand ChangeContentToGreen { get; set; }

    protected override void InitCommands()
    {
        ChangeContentToRed = new RelayCommand(
            execute: () => MainContent = new RedViewModel(),
            canExecute: () => !(MainContent is RedViewModel)
            );

        ChangeContentToGreen = new RelayCommand(
            execute: () => MainContent = new GreenViewModel(),
            canExecute: () => !(MainContent is GreenViewModel)
            );
    }
}
```

RedViewModel and GreenViewModel are empty so I don't show the code but extend ViewModel

Window.xaml

```
 <Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Path=LeftMenu}" />
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Path=MainContent}" />
</Grid>
```

Left.xaml

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModel:LeftViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button
        Grid.Row="0"
        Command="{Binding Path=ChangeContentToRed}"
        Content="Red" />
    <Button
        Grid.Row="1"
        Command="{Binding Path=ChangeContentToGreen}"
        Content="Green" />
</Grid>
```

Red and Green are only two UserControl with a red and a green grid

Comment: UserControls never have their own, private view model objects. Remove the DataContext assignments from the UserControls' XAML and bind them to properties of a common MainViewModel (which you apparently already did).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a DataTemplate like

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModelMenu:LeftViewModel}">
    <viewMenu:Left />
</DataTemplate>
```

and then assign a value of type LeftViewModel to the Content property of a ContentControl, like

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=LeftMenu}"/>
```

the DataTemplate is assigned to the ContentTemplate of the ContentControl, and the element in the instantiated DataTemplate (i.e. your UserControl) inherits the DataContext of the ContentPresenter in the ControlTemplate of the ContentControl, which then holds the Content value.

However, this only works if you do not explicitly assign the UserControl's DataContext and thus break the value inheritance of the DataContext property.

You have to remove the explicit DataContext assignment from the UserControl, i.e. this:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModel:LeftViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Comment: Thx for the quick reply. Do I have to remove all my VM (RedVM, GreenVM, LeftVM) except the MainViewModel and the ViewModel. So everything refers to the MainVM? Or not? Because if I do, I have to change the properties type (MainContent for ex) from ViemModel to UserControl... Is that OK?

Comment: Because if I only remove the UserControl.DataContext, the MainContent does not Update...

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're referring to, but if you have "sub" view models in a main view model, a change of a property in one of them should of course be communicated to another sub view model if your application logic requires this. Maybe better start with a single view model, i.e bind to properties of MainViewModel from the XAML of your UserControls.

Comment: If I refer all my views to the MainViewModel it works... But I would like each UserControl to refer to his own VM (ex. I prefer to have all the specific commands of the LeftMenu in the LeftMenuViewModel instead of in the MainViewModel). The problem is that in that case, the MainContent does not refresh, show the Content that have been changed.

Comment: As said, you'd need some kind of communication between the main and the sub view models. One vm may for example subscribe to the PropertyChanged event of another vm.

Comment: Thx... It is what I thought... But have no clue how to implement that... :D
I read about DI, +++ But I don't know what is the best way to do it. 
'll look into it... untill i found the answer ;)    Thx for your help!

Comment: `LeftMenu.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => { ... }`

Comment: But with LeftMenu.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => { ... } 
I can retrieve the property name but not which content have to be display. Wich button have been clicked..?

Comment: The execute handler methods of the ICommands could somehow update the main view model, that depends entirely on your view model structure.

Comment: The Property         private ViewModel _mainContent;

        public ViewModel MainContent
        {
            get => _mainContent;
            set
            {
                _mainContent = value;
MessageBox.Show("Here");
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        } is fired! The Messagebox is Shown but it does not display it in the ContentControl

Comment: No idea what that's going to tell me. You seemingly have trouble with the data flow between your view models. Then why do you have them, instead of a single one?

Comment: If I have a single ViewModel, it is going to be enormous... Lot's of commands, and properties...?

Comment: If you have multiple view models, you have to establish some data flow between them. You have to write code that implements it. But that is totally out of the scope of your question. One typical approach is that a parent view model subscribes to property changes of child view models. If there are commands in the child view models, these may still update properties that the parent vm can subscribe to.

Comment: Alright... I will look in that direction. Thank you for all those info!

Comment: Note that the main view can of course also directly bind to a property of a child view model, like `Text="{Binding LeftMenu.SomeText}"`